# How to interact with mayavi window while animating particles? (during Particle Swarm Optimization)

Tags: python, mayavi

I am trying to do an animation of a Particle Swarm Optimization using Python and Mayavi2.

The animation is working fine, my problem is that it is not possible to interact with the plot while it is animating the movement. Specifically i would like to turn the graph and zoom. Maybe someone has experience doing animations?

The way i do it is first to calculate the positions of the particles and then to store them. After the calculation is finished i plot the positions of the particle at the first instace of time with point3d() and then i iterate through time updating the data using the set() method.

Is there a way to make it possible to turn the graph?  I have heard about something with threads, disabeling the the rendering, but i could not figure out how to do it in my code. Besides lots of other stuff, I have read:

http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi//docs/development/html/mayavi/mlab_animating.html

http://code.enthought.com/projects/mayavi//docs/development/html/mayavi/tips.html#acceleration-mayavi-scripts

but it can't see how to use it.

Any suggestions?

Here is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
    @author rt
'''
import pylab as plt
from numpy import *
from mayavi import mlab
from threading import Thread # making plotting faster?
import ackley as ac

class Swarm(Thread, object):
    '''
        constructor for the swarm
        initializes all instance variables
    '''
    def __init__(self,objective_function):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        # optimization options
        self.omega = 0.9 # inertial constant
        self.c1 = 0.06 # cognitive/private constant
        self.c2 = 0.06 # social constant
        self.objective = objective_function # function object

        self.max_iteration = 100 # maximal number of iterations
        # Swarm stuff
        self.number = 0
        self.best = [] # gbest; the global best position
        self.particles = [] # empty list for particles
        # temporary
        self.min = self.objective.min
        self.max = self.objective.max
        self.best_evolution = []
        # self.dimensions = 2 # dimensions NB! 


    '''
        add particles to the swarm
        find the best position of particle in swarm to set global best
    '''
    def add_particles(self, n):
        for i in range(n):
            particle = Particle(self)
            if i == 0: # initialize self.best
                self.best = particle.position
            if particle.eval() < self._eval(): # check if there is a better and if, set it
                self.best = copy(particle.position) 
            self.particles.append(particle) # append the particle to the swarm    

    def _eval(self):
        return self.objective.evaluate(self.best)

    def plot(self):
        for i in range(self.max_iteration):
            pos_x = []
            pos_y = []
            pos_z = []
            #print pos_x
            for particle in self.particles:
                [x,y,z] = particle.trail[i]
                pos_x.append(x)
                pos_y.append(y)
                pos_z.append(z)
            #print pos_x
            if i ==0:
                g = mlab.points3d(pos_x, pos_y,pos_z, scale_factor=0.5)
                ms =g.mlab_source
                ms.anti_aliasing_frames = 0
            ms.set(x=pos_x, y = pos_y, z = pos_z,scale_factor=0.5)     #updating y value
            #print pos_y
            #ms.set(x=pos_x) # update x values
            #ms.set(y=pos_y)     #updating y value
            #ms.set(z=pos_z)     #updating y value

        #for p in self.particles:
            #p.plot()
    def plot_objective(self):
        delta = 0.1
        v = mgrid[self.min:self.max:delta,self.min:self.max:delta]
        z = self.objective.evaluate(v)
        #mlab.mesh(v[0],v[1],z)
        mlab.surf(v[0],v[1],z) # surf creates a more efficient data structure than mesh
        mlab.xlabel('x-axis', object=None)
        mlab.ylabel('y-axis', object=None)
        mlab.zlabel('z-axis', object=None)


    def _info(self):
        self.plot()
        print '----------------------------'
        print 'The best result is:'
        print 'Coordinates:', self.best
        print 'Value: ', self._eval()
        #print 'with ', nreval, 'evaluations'
        print 'nr of particles: ', len(self.particles)
        print '----------------------------'  

    def run(self):
        self.plot_objective()
        self.best = self.particles[0].get_position()  
        iteration = 0
        while iteration < self.max_iteration:
            #if iteration!= 0: obj.scene.disable_render = True
            #disable_render = True
            for particle in self.particles:
                rnd_c1 = array([random.uniform(0,1),random.uniform(0,1)])
                rnd_c2 = array([random.uniform(0,1),random.uniform(0,1)])
                particle.velocity = self.omega * array(particle.velocity) + \
                                    self.c1 * rnd_c1 * (array(particle.best) - array(particle.position)) + \
                                    self.c2 * rnd_c2 * (array(self.best) - array(particle.position)) # TODO: change so independent rnd for components
                particle.position = array(particle.position) + particle.velocity
                if particle.eval() < particle.best_eval():
                    particle.best = copy(particle.position)
                    if particle.eval() < self._eval():
                        self.best = copy(particle.position)
                particle.update() # add the point to the trail
            iteration +=1
            self.best_evolution.append(self._eval())
            #obj.scene.disable_render = False
        print 'finished: ', iteration
        self._info()

'''
    Class modeling particle
'''
class Particle():
    def __init__(self, swarm):
        self.swarm = swarm
        x_rand = random.uniform(self.swarm.min,self.swarm.max)
        y_rand = random.uniform(self.swarm.min,self.swarm.max)
        self.position = array([x_rand,y_rand])
        v_x_rand = random.uniform(self.swarm.min,self.swarm.max)
        v_y_rand = random.uniform(self.swarm.min,self.swarm.max)
        self.velocity = array([v_x_rand, v_y_rand])
        self.size = 0.5
        self.best = self.position
        # visualization
        self.trail = []

    def plot(self):
        [x,y] = self.position
        z = self.eval()
        mlab.points3d(x,y,z,scale_factor=self.size)
    def eval(self):
        return self.swarm.objective.evaluate(self.position)
    def best_eval(self):
        return self.swarm.objective.evaluate(self.best)
    def get_position(self):
        return self.position
    def update(self):
        [x,y] = self.position
        z = self.eval()
        #print [x,y,z]
        self.trail.append([x,y,z])
    def plot_trail(self,index):
        [x,y,z] = self.trail[index]
        mlab.points3d(x,y,z,scale_factor=self.size)

# Make the animation
mlab.figure(1, bgcolor=(0, 0, 0), size=(1300, 700)) # create a new figure with black background and size 1300x700

objective = ac.Ackley() # make an objective function

swarm = pso.Swarm(objective) # create a swarm
nr_of_particles = 25 # nr of particles in swarm

swarm.add_particles(nr_of_particles)      
swarm.run()
#swarm.start()
mlab.show()

print '------------------------------------------------------'
print 'Particle Swarm Optimization'
#objective.info()
print 'Objective function to minimize has dimension = ', objective.get_dimension()
print '# of iterations = ', 1000
print '# of particles in swarm = ', nr_of_particles
print '------------------------------------------------------'
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, even though I was somewhat able to do what Brandon Rhodes suggested for a mock program (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16617814/interacting-with-mlab-scene-while-it-is-being-drawn), I could not manage to convert my already existing larger program.

Then I found this link: http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

So, I just sprinkled a lot of `wx.Yield()` s inside my loops. This way I did not need to change my program structure, and I am able to interact with the window. I think better ways are explained in the link.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the `wx` event loop, which runs the Mayavi GUI window and listens for mouse clicking and dragging and responds by moving the scene, is not getting any time to run during your animation because you are keeping Python captive in your loop without ever letting it `return` control.

Instead of keeping control of the program with a loop of your own, you need to create a `wx.Timer` class that advances the scene by one frame update, and that then returns control to the `wx` event loop after scheduling itself again. It will look something like this:

```
import wx

...

class Animator(wx.Timer):

    def Notify(self):
        """When a wx.Timer goes off, it calls its Notify() method."""

        if (...the animation is complete...):
            return

        # Otherwise, update all necessary data to advance one step
        # in the animation; you might need to keep a counter or
        # other state as an instance variable on `self`

        # [DATA UPDATE GOES HERE]

        # Schedule ourselves again, giving the wx event loop time to
        # process any pending mouse motion.

        self.Start(0, oneShot=True)  # "in zero milliseconds, call me again!"
```

I played with slightly higher values like `1` for the number of milliseconds that `wx` gets to run the UI with, but could not really tell a difference between that and just choosing `0` and having control returned "immediately".